# How can I get the names of the applications that are installed on an application server?

Tags: unix, server, application-server

I have an SSH access to my application. Is there any UNIX code that I can use to get the name of the applications installed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually I don't understand when you talk about "my applicattion" or "applications installed" what are you exactly refering.

1) If you want to know what applications are deployed, for example in the application server of your instance, for example Tomcat 7 you can take a look here: [List Currently Deployed Applications](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#List_Currently_Deployed_Applications)

2) Or maybe you are looking for SO installed applications. 
Depeending on what OS is running may be different. For example for Red Hat Enterprise / Fedora Linux / Suse Linux / Cent OS:

Under Red Hat/Fedora Linux:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep {package-name}
```

For example find out package *mutt* installed or not:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep mutt
```

Output:

```
mutt-1.4.1-10
```

If you don't get any output ( package name along with version), it means package is not installed at all. You can display list all installed packages with the following command:

```
$ rpm -qa
$ rpm -qa | less
```

3) Another useful command is ps command. You can check what is running with the ps command.

Type the following ps command to display all running process:

```
ps aux | less
```

Where,

- A: select all processes
- a: select all processes on a terminal, including those of other users
- x: select processes without controlling ttys

Task: see every process on the system

```
ps -A
ps -e
```